# Convert flat JSON file to hierarchical json data like flare.json [d3 example file]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

After a troublesome fight i almost figured how to convert a flat json file to a Hierarchical one. I didn't write the function by my own. I copied it from the below post.

[D3 JSON DATA CONVERSION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912966/d3-json-data-conversion)

But now the problem now is, the function which was written in the post has just 2 levels of hierarchy. But i'm looking for 4 levels hierarchy. I tried to override the function where i failed but.

**Code with what i'm trying.**

```
    
         var data = [
        { "dep": "First Top", "name": "First child", "model": "value1", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "First Top", "name": "First child", "model": "value2", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "First Top", "name": "First child", "model": "value3", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "First Top", "name": "First child", "model": "value4", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "First Top", "name": "SECOND CHILD", "model": "value1", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "First Top", "name": "SECOND CHILD", "model": "value2", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "First Top", "name": "SECOND CHILD", "model": "value3", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "First Top", "name": "SECOND CHILD", "model": "value4", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "Second Top", "name": "First Child", "model": "value1", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "Second Top", "name": "First Child", "model": "value2", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "Second Top", "name": "First Child", "model": "value3", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "Second Top", "name": "First Child", "model": "value4", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "Second Top", "name": "SECOND CHILD", "model": "value1", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "Second Top", "name": "SECOND CHILD", "model": "value2", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "Second Top", "name": "SECOND CHILD", "model": "value3", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "Second Top", "name": "SECOND CHILD", "model": "value4", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "Third Top", "name": "First Child", "model": "value2", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "Third Top", "name": "First Child", "model": "value3", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "Third Top", "name": "First Child", "model": "value4", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "Third Top", "name": "First Child", "model": "value5", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "Third Top", "name": "Second Child", "model": "value1", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "Third Top", "name": "Second Child", "model": "value2", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "Third Top", "name": "Second Child", "model": "value3", "size": "320" },
        { "dep": "Third Top", "name": "Second Child", "model": "value4", "size": "320" }
      ]

    var newData = {"name":"root", "children":{}}

    data.forEach(function(d){
        if(typeof newData.children[d.dep] !== 'undefined')  {
            newData.children[d.dep].children.push(d)
        } else {
            newData.children[d.dep] = {"name": d.dep, "children": [{"name": d.name, "children": [{"name": d.model, "size": d.size}]}]}
        }
    })





    newData.children = Object.keys(newData.children).map(function (key) { return newData.children[key]; });

              // show what we've got
              d3.select('body').append('pre')
                  .text(JSON.stringify(newData, null, '  '));
```

**Output of the current code**

```
    {
      "name": "root",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "First Top",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "First child",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "value1",
                  "size": "320"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "dep": "First Top",
              "name": "First child",
              "model": "value2",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "First Top",
              "name": "First child",
              "model": "value3",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "First Top",
              "name": "First child",
              "model": "value4",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "First Top",
              "name": "SECOND CHILD",
              "model": "value1",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "First Top",
              "name": "SECOND CHILD",
              "model": "value2",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "First Top",
              "name": "SECOND CHILD",
              "model": "value3",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "First Top",
              "name": "SECOND CHILD",
              "model": "value4",
              "size": "320"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Second Top",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "First Child",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "value1",
                  "size": "320"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "dep": "Second Top",
              "name": "First Child",
              "model": "value2",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "Second Top",
              "name": "First Child",
              "model": "value3",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "Second Top",
              "name": "First Child",
              "model": "value4",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "Second Top",
              "name": "SECOND CHILD",
              "model": "value1",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "Second Top",
              "name": "SECOND CHILD",
              "model": "value2",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "Second Top",
              "name": "SECOND CHILD",
              "model": "value3",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "Second Top",
              "name": "SECOND CHILD",
              "model": "value4",
              "size": "320"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Third Top",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "First Child",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "value2",
                  "size": "320"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "dep": "Third Top",
              "name": "First Child",
              "model": "value3",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "Third Top",
              "name": "First Child",
              "model": "value4",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "Third Top",
              "name": "First Child",
              "model": "value5",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "Third Top",
              "name": "Second Child",
              "model": "value1",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "Third Top",
              "name": "Second Child",
              "model": "value2",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "Third Top",
              "name": "Second Child",
              "model": "value3",
              "size": "320"
            },
            {
              "dep": "Third Top",
              "name": "Second Child",
              "model": "value4",
              "size": "320"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

**Desired Output Format:**

```
    {
      "name": "root",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "First Top",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "First child",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "value1",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value2",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value3",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value4",
                  "size": "320"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "Second child",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "value1",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value2",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value3",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value4",
                  "size": "320"
                }
              ]
            },

          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Second Top",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "First child",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "value1",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value2",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value3",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value4",
                  "size": "320"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "Second child",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "value1",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value2",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value3",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value4",
                  "size": "320"
                }
              ]
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Third Top",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "First child",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "value1",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value2",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value3",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value4",
                  "size": "320"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "Second child",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "value1",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value2",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value3",
                  "size": "320"
                },
                {
                  "name": "value4",
                  "size": "320"
                }
              ]
            },
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

I'm cracking my head from a week but i alone couldn't figure it out. Someone please amend the function to get the data in the hierarchical format as i've updated.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Updated to use a recursive method**

This should work for `n` levels rather than just 2 or 3. You just need to specify which properties define which levels.

```
var data = [
    { "dep": "First Top", "name": "First child", "model": "value1", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "First Top", "name": "First child", "model": "value2", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "First Top", "name": "SECOND CHILD", "model": "value1", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "Second Top", "name": "First Child", "model": "value1", "size": "320" }
];

var newData = { name :"root", children : [] },
    levels = ["dep","name"];

// For each data row, loop through the expected levels traversing the output tree
data.forEach(function(d){
    // Keep this as a reference to the current level
    var depthCursor = newData.children;
    // Go down one level at a time
    levels.forEach(function( property, depth ){

        // Look to see if a branch has already been created
        var index;
        depthCursor.forEach(function(child,i){
            if ( d[property] == child.name ) index = i;
        });
        // Add a branch if it isn't there
        if ( isNaN(index) ) {
            depthCursor.push({ name : d[property], children : []});
            index = depthCursor.length - 1;
        }
        // Now reference the new child array as we go deeper into the tree
        depthCursor = depthCursor[index].children;
        // This is a leaf, so add the last element to the specified branch
        if ( depth === levels.length - 1 ) depthCursor.push({ name : d.model, size : d.size });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi - Richard. Thanks for the reply. But I couldn't get the name column in the json format. I'm getting the dep column values followed by model value. Between these two i need to add name i.e, dep > name > value. How do i do it. I'm not that good in editing the function. I tried changing this line - newData.children[d.dep].children[childIndex] = { name : d.name, children[{ name : d.model, size : d.size }]}; but couldn't get it. Thanks in advance again.

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard. After a many days of struggle i was able to do it with your help. Thanks a lot again!!

Comment: Hi Richard - Please help me with this [**post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737829/d3-help-required-in-editing-function).

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = [
    { "state": "UP", "district": "Agra", "block": "IradatNagar","school":"APS","name":"A" },
    { "state": "UP", "district": "Agra", "block": "IradatNagar","school":"IPS","name":"B" },
    { "state": "UP", "district": "Agra", "block": "IradatNagar","school":"APS","name":"C" },
    { "state": "MP", "district": "Bhopal", "block": "chota_Bhopal","school":"DPS","name":"D" },
    { "state": "UP", "district": "Mathura", "block": "Farah","school":"HPS","name":"E" },
    { "state": "UP", "district": "Kanpur", "block": "Mania","school":"BPs","name":"F" },
    { "state": "UP", "district": "Agra", "block": "Arjun Nagar","school":"GPS","name":"G" }, 
    { "state": "MP", "district": "Gwalior", "block": "Surya Nagar","school":"DPS","name":"H" }
];

var newData = { name :"State", children : [] },
    levels = ["state","district","block","school"];

data.forEach(function(d){
    var depthCursor = newData.children;
    levels.forEach(function( property, depth )
    {
        var index;
        depthCursor.forEach(function(child,i)
        {
            if ( d[property] == child.name ) 
                index = i;
        });

        if ( isNaN(index) ) 
        {
            depthCursor.push({name : d[property], children : []});
            index = depthCursor.length - 1;
        }

        depthCursor = depthCursor[index].children;

        if ( depth === levels.length - 1 )
        {
            depthCursor.push({ name : d.name});
        }
    });
});

console.log(newData);
```