# Node.js - Convert flat json to hierarchical json without 'parent','child' attributes

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, templates, hierarchical-data

I want to build a hierarchical data structure from my sql query.
After following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317115/convert-flat-json-file-to-hierarchical-json-data-like-flare-json-d3-example-fil) for build hierarchical JSON object from flat objects, I try to create 4 level hierarchy with more attributes in object levels, but don't need children property.

How can i do this?

**Here is my JavaScript (NodeJS) code:**

```
var levels = ["counties_id","district_id", "municipalities_id", "institutes_id"];
data.forEach(function(d){
    var depthCursor = newData.counties;
    levels.forEach(function( property, depth ){
        var index;
        depthCursor.forEach(function(child,i){
            if ( d[property] == child.counties_id ) index = i;
        });
        if ( isNaN(index) ) {
            var propname = levels[depth];
            var obj = {};
            obj[propname] = d[property];
            obj["children"] = [];
            depthCursor.push(obj);
            index = depthCursor.length - 1;
        }
        depthCursor = depthCursor[index].children;
        if ( depth === levels.length - 1 ) {
            depthCursor.push({ id : d.id, name : d.name, name_H : d.name_h });
        }
    });
});
```

First level is ok because this equalation check the same first level attributes:

```
if ( d[property] == child.counties_id ) index = i;
```

How can i chect 2th, 3th and 4th level same case?

**This is the flat object which keep trying:**

```
[
{
"counties_h":"Megye 1",
"counties_en":"Coun 1",
"counties_id":"1",
"district_h":"Korz 1",
"district_en":"Dist 1",
"district_id":"101",
"municipalities_h":"Onk 1",
"municipalities_en":"Mun 1",
"municipalities_id":"asdf",
"institutes_h":"Int 1",
"institites_en":"Inst 1",
"institutes_id":"1"
},
{
"counties_h":"Megye 1",
"counties_en":"Coun 1",
"counties_id":"1",
"district_h":"Korz 1",
"district_en":"Dist 1",
"district_id":"101",
"municipalities_h":"Onk 1",
"municipalities_en":"Mun 1",
"municipalities_id":"asdf",
"institutes_h":"Int 2",
"institites_en":"Inst 2",
"institutes_id":"2"
},
{
"counties_h":"Megye 1",
"counties_en":"Coun 1",
"counties_id":"1",
"district_h":"Korz 1",
"district_en":"Dist 1",
"district_id":"101",
"municipalities_h":"Onk 2",
"municipalities_en":"Mun 2",
"municipalities_id":"sdfg",
"institutes_h":"Int 1",
"institites_en":"Inst 1",
"institutes_id":"1"
},
{
"counties_h":"Megye 1",
"counties_en":"Coun 1",
"counties_id":"1",
"district_h":"Korz 1",
"district_en":"Dist 1",
"district_id":"101",
"municipalities_h":"Onk 2",
"municipalities_en":"Mun 2",
"municipalities_id":"sdfg",
"institutes_h":"Int 2",
"institites_en":"Inst 2",
"institutes_id":"2"
},
{
"counties_h":"Megye 1",
"counties_en":"Coun 1",
"counties_id":"1",
"district_h":"Korz 2",
"district_en":"Dist 2",
"district_id":"102",
"municipalities_h":"Onk 1",
"municipalities_en":"Mun 1",
"municipalities_id":"dfgh",
"institutes_h":"Int 1",
"institites_en":"Inst 1",
"institutes_id":"1"
},
{
"counties_h":"Megye 1",
"counties_en":"Coun 1",
"counties_id":"1",
"district_h":"Korz 2",
"district_en":"Dist 2",
"district_id":"102",
"municipalities_h":"Onk 1",
"municipalities_en":"Mun 1",
"municipalities_id":"dfgh",
"institutes_h":"Int 2",
"institites_en":"Inst 2",
"institutes_id":"2"
},
{
"counties_h":"Megye 2",
"counties_en":"Coun 2",
"counties_id":"2",
"district_h":"Korz 2",
"district_en":"Dist 2",
"district_id":"202",
"municipalities_h":"Onk 1",
"municipalities_en":"Mun 1",
"municipalities_id":"fghj",
"institutes_h":"Int 1",
"institites_en":"Inst 1",
"institutes_id":"1"
},
{
"counties_h":"Megye 2",
"counties_en":"Coun 2",
"counties_id":"2",
"district_h":"Korz 2",
"district_en":"Dist 2",
"district_id":"202",
"municipalities_h":"Onk 1",
"municipalities_en":"Mun 1",
"municipalities_id":"fghj",
"institutes_h":"Int 2",
"institites_en":"Inst 2",
"institutes_id":"2"
}
]
```

**Output of my current code:**

```
{
   "counties":[
      {
         "counties_id":"1",
         "children":[
            {
               "district_id":"101",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "municipalities_id":"asdf",
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "institutes_id":"1",
                           "children":[
                              {

                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "district_id":"101",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "municipalities_id":"asdf",
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "institutes_id":"2",
                           "children":[
                              {

                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "district_id":"101",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "municipalities_id":"sdfg",
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "institutes_id":"1",
                           "children":[
                              {

                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "district_id":"101",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "municipalities_id":"sdfg",
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "institutes_id":"2",
                           "children":[
                              {

                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "district_id":"102",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "municipalities_id":"dfgh",
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "institutes_id":"1",
                           "children":[
                              {

                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "district_id":"102",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "municipalities_id":"dfgh",
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "institutes_id":"2",
                           "children":[
                              {

                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "counties_id":"2",
         "children":[
            {
               "district_id":"202",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "municipalities_id":"fghj",
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "institutes_id":"1",
                           "children":[
                              {

                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "district_id":"202",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "municipalities_id":"fghj",
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "institutes_id":"2",
                           "children":[
                              {

                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**And this is what I want:**

```
{
   "counties":[
      {
         "counties_id":"1",
         "counties_h":"Megye 1",
         "counties_en":"Coun 1",
         "districts":[
            {
               "district_id":"101",
               "district_h":"Korz 1",
               "district_en":"Dist 1",
               "municipalities":[
                  {
                     "municipalities_id":"asdf",
                     "municipalities_h":"Onk 1",
                     "municipalities_en":"Mun 1",
                     "institutes":[
                        {
                           "institutes_id":"1",
                           "institutes_h":"Int 1",
                           "institutes_en":"Inst 1"
                        },
                        {
                           "institutes_id":"2",
                           "institutes_h":"Int 2",
                           "institutes_en":"Inst 2"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "municipalities_id":"sdfg",
                     "municipalities_h":"Onk 2",
                     "municipalities_en":"Mun 2",
                     "institutes":[
                        {
                           "institutes_id":"3",
                           "institutes_h":"Int 1",
                           "institutes_en":"Inst 1"
                        },
                        {
                           "institutes_id":"4",
                           "institutes_h":"Int 2",
                           "institutes_en":"Inst 2"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "district_id":"102",
               "district_h":"Korz 2",
               "district_en":"Dist 2",
               "municipalities":[
                  {
                     "municipalities_id":"dfgh",
                     "municipalities_h":"Onk 1",
                     "municipalities_en":"Mun 1",
                     "institutes":[
                        {
                           "institutes_id":"5",
                           "institutes_h":"Int 1",
                           "institutes_en":"Inst 1"
                        },
                        {
                           "institutes_id":"6",
                           "institutes_h":"Int 2",
                           "institutes_en":"Inst 2"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "counties_id":"2",
         "counties_h":"Megye 2",
         "counties_en":"Coun 2",
         "districts":[
            {
               "district_id":"202",
               "district_h":"Korz 2",
               "district_en":"Dist 2",
               "municipalities":[
                  {
                     "municipalities_id":"fghj",
                     "municipalities_h":"Onk 1",
                     "municipalities_en":"Mun 1",
                     "institutes":[
                        {
                           "institutes_id":"7",
                           "institutes_h":"Int 1",
                           "institutes_en":"Inst 1"
                        },
                        {
                           "institutes_id":"8",
                           "institutes_h":"Int 2",
                           "institutes_en":"Inst 2"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: JSON should be formatted in the server and sent to the client. The method in which you are trying is a bad practise.

Comment: This JSON formatted in server side (with NodeJS) and the output whatt i will send to client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [shape-json module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shape-json) on NPM.

It will make your life much simpler.