# How to prepare array of json objects to d3 hierarchical tree structure

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a collapsible tree diagram in D3v4 like [this](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd). I have my data as an array of JSON objects and need to prepare the data into a hierarchical tree structure.

My data looks likes this:

```
[
  {
    "ingoingBatch": "BC1",
    "process": "API",
    "outgoingBatch": "CD1",
    "counterIndex": "5"
  },
  {
    "ingoingBatch": "BC2",
    "process": "API",
    "outgoingBatch": "CD1",
    "counterIndex": "6"
  },
  {
    "ingoingBatch": "AB1",
    "process": "PUR",
    "outgoingBatch": "BC1",
    "counterIndex": "1"
  },
  {
    "ingoingBatch": "AB2",
    "process": "PUR",
    "outgoingBatch": "BC1",
    "counterIndex": "2"
  },
  {
    "ingoingBatch": "AB3",
    "process": "PUR",
    "outgoingBatch": "BC2",
    "counterIndex": "3"
  },
  {
    "ingoingBatch": "AB4",
    "process": "PUR",
    "outgoingBatch": "BC2",
    "counterIndex": "4"
  }
]
```

The structure I wanted is something like [this structure](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/17/cea28693d5d4fa0c0c0afa31ddab5eb1-full.png)

I have tried making a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeppeskajaa/qLm7bg3y/37/) where you can see the original data on line 129-142. I have inserted my own data on line 11-115 and used the function d3 function nest as found [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/v1.0.7/README.md#nests) on line 117-126:

```
var entries = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.ingoingBatch; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.outgoingBatch; })
    .entries(json);

console.log(entries);

var treeData = d3.hierarchy(entries);

console.log(treeData);
```

I assume the problem is within the data preparation. The error message I get when I run the JSfiddle with my data is:
`TypeError: root.children is undefined`

The root node should be C1 and the structure should look like this:

```
           C1 
    B2            B1
 A1    A2      A3    A4
```

The link between the nodes is the ingoingBatch and outgoingBatch. 
Can anybody please help prepare my data to get my data preparation just right?

**-----------UPDATE-----------**

If I use the answer from here [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317115/convert-flat-json-file-to-hierarchical-json-data-like-flare-json-d3-example-fil) I get a bit closer on having the right data structure. When I instead of this:

```
var entries = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.ingoingBatch; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.outgoingBatch; })
    .entries(json);

console.log(entries);

var treeData = d3.hierarchy(entries);

console.log(treeData);
```

Use the the answer from the other question and have this function instead:

```
var newData = { name :"root", children : [] },
    levels = ["outgoingBatch"];
    // levels = ["ingoingBatch","outgoingBatch"];

// For each data row, loop through the expected levels traversing the output tree
json.forEach(function(d){
    // Keep this as a reference to the current level
    var depthCursor = newData.children;
    // Go down one level at a time
    levels.forEach(function( property, depth ){

        // Look to see if a branch has already been created
        var index;
        depthCursor.forEach(function(child,i){
            if ( d[property] == child.name ) index = i;
        });
        // Add a branch if it isn't there
        if ( isNaN(index) ) {
            depthCursor.push({ name : d[property], children : []});
            index = depthCursor.length - 1;
        }
        // Now reference the new child array as we go deeper into the tree
        depthCursor = depthCursor[index].children;
        // This is a leaf, so add the last element to the specified branch
        if ( depth === levels.length - 1 ) depthCursor.push({ outgoingBatch : d.outgoingBatch });
    });
});

var treeData = newData
console.log(treeData);
```

I get a three diagram out. But it is not structured correctly, since CD1 is not set as the root node but instead one of the children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to return the root node from the place I get the JSON objects. In this way I could use that and make the JSON objects the child of this with the code from the update.